# PhoneGap & Facebook Connect - How to implement in a "domain-less" context?  [An Error Occurred..Please Try Again Later]

Tags: ios, facebook, cordova

I am using PhoneGap 2.0 for iOS and trying to get FB JS SDK working.  I'm loading the SDK asyncronously using the follow params:

```
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
                appId : 'xxxx', // App ID
                status : true, // check login status
                cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                xfbml : true  // parse XFBML
            });   
        ....
```

I have a Facebook app tied to "localhost".  When I test the page using the XCode simulator or when opening up my index.html page in a browser (Firefox, Chrome, etc) from my filesystem, I get:

"An error occurred with [APPNAME]. Please try again later."

If I hit the same file through a local apache instance (localhost:8080/index.html) it works just fine.

I noticed that the URL of the FB popup passes along your domain in the querystring.  On localhost:8080, it passes "domain=localhost".  But in Xcode and from the filesystem it passes "domain=" and gives the above error each time.

Is there a correct way to either configure the FB app to work in a "domain-less" context, or would you setup the FB.init in a different manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the Facebook Connect Plugin:
https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect
(Check the branch, cordova-2.0-facebook-ios-3.0, if using with the Facebook SDK 3.0 for iOS)

See if that is what you're looking for. The plugin needs to be updated for the just released Facebook SDK 3.1, but should nonetheless be functional. Only issue is if you're running on iOS6 it will not auth against the native iOS6 credentials without a few changes. It will auth by fast app-switching to FB iOS app or FB web app.

Comment: This is definitely the way to go.  For others, make sure to download the latest versions of all the major pieces in the stack first, it was a lot of extra work for us but it got rid of all our lingering dependency issues.  We moved to PhoneGap 2.2 (from 2.0) and Facebook iOS SDK 3.1.1 (from 3.0).  And also needed to go to XCode 4.5 (from 4.4) and iOS SDK 6.0 (from 5.1).